# SpringBoot: Serving JSON requests with some fields missing

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest, lombok

I'm building a POJO class to match some requests coming my way in a REST API implemented on SpringBoot. Some of the data *has* to be given to me, otherwise I am not willing to even serve the request. To make sure the client gives me at least what I *absolutely* need, I have used Lombok's `@NonNull`:

```java
@Data
public class ProductRequestBody implements Serializable
{
    private String name;
    private String category;
    private String description;
    private String abbreviation;
    private String labelColor;
    private Double cost;

    public ProductRequestBody()
    {
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public ProductRequestBody(@NonNull @JsonProperty("name") String name,
                              @NonNull @JsonProperty("category") String category,
                              @JsonProperty("description") String description,
                              @NonNull @JsonProperty("cost") Double cost)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.category = category;
        this.description = description;
        this.cost = cost;
    }
}
```

*(I completely understand that handling monetary quantities as `Double`s is a no-no; this is just an example.*

Processing this from my controller is as easy as a listener on the `/products` endpoint like so:

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/products")
public Product postProduct(@RequestBody ProductRequestBody newProduct)
{
   // ... 
   // Serve the request appropriately
   // ... 
}
```

Now, if I receive a POST request with a `null` field that has *not* been marked as `@NonNull`, like the following, I can serve it without issue:

```json
{
        "name": "Some Product Name",
        "category": "Some Product Category", 
        "cost" : 10.0,
        "description": null
}
```

My goal, however, is to be able to handle `JSON` requests that simply don't even have the fields they don't care about. That is, I want to be able to serve the following as well, and I currently can't:

```json
{
        "name": "Some Product Name",
        "category": "Some Product Category", 
        "cost" : 10.0,
        // No "description" field in this payload
}
```

How could I go about doing this? The less code, the better, as always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use spring-boot and lombok you can simplify your class to be like this:

```
@Data
public class ProductRequestBody implements Serializable {

    @NonNull
    private String name;

    @NonNull
    private String category;

    @NonNull
    private Double cost;

    private String description;
    private String abbreviation;
    private String labelColor;
}
```

it will return 400 if name, category or cost will be not provided and 200 otherwise.

Comment: You were absolutely correct, I did not know that Spring pattern - matches as naturally as it does. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Spring handles serializing and deserializing json without any issue.
You should let spring handle it.
You can try the following.

```
@Data
public class ProductRequestBody implements Serializable {
    @NonNull
    private String name;
    @NonNull
    private String category;
    private String description;
    private String abbreviation;
    private String labelColor;
    @NonNull
    private Double cost;
}
```

If you really want to follow the pattern of creating a constructor, then you should create a constructor with only the `@NonNull` fields and create getter of others (`lombok` handles that for you). If you want to add `@JsonProperty` then you need to create separate getter.

```
@Data                                                                                
public class ProductRequestBody implements Serializable                              
{                                                                                    
    private String name;                                                             
    private String category;                                                         
    private String description;                                                      
    private String abbreviation;                                                     
    private String labelColor;                                                       
    private Double cost;                                                             
                                                                                     
    public ProductRequestBody()                                                      
    {                                                                                
    }                                                                                
                                                                                     
    @JsonCreator                                                                     
    public ProductRequestBody(@NonNull @JsonProperty("name") String name,            
                              @NonNull @JsonProperty("category") String category,    
                              @NonNull @JsonProperty("cost") Double cost)            
    {                                                                                
        this.name = name;                                                            
        this.category = category;                                                    
        this.cost = cost;                                                            
    }                                                                                
                                                                                     
    @JsonProperty("description")                                                     
    public String getDescription() {                                                 
        return description;                                                          
    }                                                                                
}
```

Comment: You were absolutely correct, I did not know that Spring pattern - matches as naturally as it does. Thank you. For my information, is there perhaps a use-case where you would recommend the constructor - based pattern?